# Vuejs select dynamic (multiple) elements

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am using VueJS with a PHP application. I have multiple posts with comments for each of them. Each of them has a class `answer_comment`. I am trying to make VueJS work for all of them (it currently only works with one).

```
new Vue({ el: '.answer_comment', /* other code */ })
```

This only affects the first one. How can I make it work for all of them? How can I select all elements with the class of `answer_comment` instead of only getting the first one?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Since this answer was given, Vue now disallows mounting a VM on the `body` tag. So, use some element beneath it.

Using the `new Vue` approach is really just setting up a single View Model with its own hierarchy. It will end up just matching the first DOM element that matches your CSS selector.

In this case, I recommend moving your `new Vue` up to the `body` tag and declare an "answer_comment" component for it that Vue will then apply throughout the `body` when it "compiles" it.

See the component documentation for more information:

http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html